# PHP PDO - How to check if database created successfully ? (MS SQL Server)

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am executing a query that creates a database. I want to check if the query was successfull. The database is sql server. Thank you in advance for your help...

```
 $dbh = new \PDO("sqlsrv:Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;", "login", "password");
 $dbh = $dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE some_name;");
```

Comment: Why did you deleted your old question? You could edited it!

Comment: You could check if the db exists?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creation, you can look use `SELECT DATABASES LIKE 'database_name'`
When the result contains one entry, you know it has been created.

Example code:

```
$dbh = new \PDO("sqlsrv:Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;", "login", "password");
$dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE some_name;");
$db_check = $dbh->query("SHOW DATABSES LIKE 'some_name'");

if ($db_check->rowCount() > 0) {
  // CREATED 
} else {
  // NOT CREATED
}
```

Comment: Hello Aron. I use try/catch and as I said in my post the query is successfull. But right after the exec (in the try block) I would like to check if it was successfull...

Comment: Oops, sorry, missed that part. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I got the following msg: "Call to a member function exec() on a non-object" for the line "$db_check...". Nevertheless the database has been created successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    $dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE some_name;");

   } catch (PDOException $e) {
    $e.getMessage();
}
```

or you can do something like

```
if($db->query("CREATE DATABASE some_name")){
     echo "database created";
}else{
     echo "there was a problem creating database";
}
```